# Why byte casting returns decimal value of char?

Tags: java, python

I have Python background and I don't understand that how byte casting returns decimal value of char according to ASCII.

Here are the some code examples:

```
// C#
string s = "abc123éé";
int[] x = new int[255];

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++){
    amount[(byte)s[i] - (byte)'0']++;
}
```

If we look for first iteration the casting is on 'a' char and it returns 97.

```
// Java
char a = 'a';
System.out.println((byte)a);
```

Same as Java, it returns 97 too. But in Python 3, it does not return as decimal value of char.

```
>>> a = bytes("a", encoding="utf-8")
>>> a
b'a'
```

And now if we're coming to my questions:

- How / Why byte casting works like this?
- I know that byte's value range is -128 to 127 but char's is 0 to 255. How does not it give an exception even 'é' value is 233?
- What's the difference between Python at this point?

Comment: 97 decimal is 0x61.  There is no difference except the way the tool is display number.

Comment: I know that byte's value range is -128 to 127 but char's is 0 to 255. How does not it give an exception even 'é' value is 233? ... those are definitions from DIFFERENT languages. What makes you think a java char has anything to do with a python char?

Comment: Python does not have char, but I wanted to mean How C# is not giving an exception even has this range definitions @GhostCat.

Comment: `System.out.println((byte)a);` prints 97 because there is no `println(byte)` overload in `PrintStream`. You are invoking `println(int)`.

Comment: The range of a byte is 0-255. Python doesn't have signed bytes. Python's default representation of a bytesting is to show ascii printable characters as characters, control characters that have escapes (like `\n`) as those escapes, and only shows them as hex escapes as a last resort. This is purely a representation issue. Python offers you ample facilities to display bytestrings in other ways, but it can't guess that you want to display `b"hello world"` as hex escapes.

Answer (score 1):

Only for Java, I do not use Python:

> - How / Why byte casting works like this?

It is specified by the Java Language Specification, mostly [JLS-5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3-230):
 *"...A narrowing conversion of a char to an integral type T likewise simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the resulting value to be a negative number, even though chars represent 16-bit unsigned integer values..."* 
<sub>("Why?" because it is so specified)</sub>

> - I know that byte's value range is -128 to 127 but char's is 0 to 255. How does not it give an exception even 'é' value is 233?

Wrong, chars are 0 to 65535 (or `'\u0000'` to `'\uFFFF'`) [JLS-4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1-100-E)
No reason for Exception, it will result in the byte value `-23` (same bits as `'é'` or int `233`)

<sub>I must pass the last point/question, I do not know enough Python</sub>